# CSS Flexbox grow

Tags: html, css, tree, flexbox, treecontrol

I am using Angular tree control Light Style (http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/) for my left panel (.tree). I have items displayed next to the tree (as displayed in Image 1). As my tree expands, the .graph item moves down as shown in Image 2. I would like my .graph to stay in place when the tree expands (Image 3). I am using flexbox but the graph continues to shift down. (CSS & HTML below)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

```css
.mainClass{
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tree{
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.tiles {
 width: 12rem; 
}

.graph{
 max-width: 50%; 
 height: 520px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainClass">
 <treecontrol class="tree">
  </treecontrol>

  <div class="tiles">
  </div>

  <div class="graph">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your `<treecontrol class="tree"` tag is broken. It would help if you could give us the rendered HTML so you aren't dependent upon finding someone who uses treecontrol being able to help if it's just a simple CSS flexbox issue.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I edited the missing tag. My main issue is keeping the .tiles & .graph divs static as the .tree div grows